# How to get the current cursor position in python readline

Tags: python, readline

I have a custom python readline completer function, in the completer function I call `readline.get_line_buffer()` which gives me the current text input so that I can complete the current word in a context-sensitive way.

What I am missing now is the possibility to get the current cursor position. For example, the position is required to determine the preceding command if possible arguments are to be completed.

In [the python readline module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html), I haven't found a way to determine the position, so how is it done?

Comment: I have the same question. I'm using pyreadline on Windows and didn't see anything simple in rlmain.py in the pyreadline source code. I wonder if before = readline.get_line_buffer(), readline.insert_text("t"), after = readline.get_line_buffer(), readline.insert_text("\b") would work. Then you could diff before and after to see where they first differ. Depends on if the backspace ("\b") works.

Comment: Another idea is to use the text variable in the tab_complete hook. I tested and you can get your current position in the line buffer, as long as the cursor's at the end of a word and not preceded by whitespace, and there isn't any duplicate text on the line :|.

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the [pyreadline source code](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline) and figured this out. The following works in pyreadline (Windows port of readline) on Python 2.7:

```
from pyreadline import Readline
readline = Readline()
cursor = readline.mode.l_buffer.point
```

Note that this works in pyreadline (Windows), but not in GNU readline (per Binabik's comment below).

Comment: I am on GNU/Linux with Python 3.9 where I am importing 'readline' instead of 'pyreadline' like you do. The 'readline' module does not offer the 'mode' attribute so just copying your code fails with the following exception: module 'readline' has no attribute 'mode'